# C++ enum placement confusion

Tags: c++, types, enums

I'm trying to use an enum in C++

Now when I place the enum above a declaration of the enum, it works. But if I declare the enum type first, I'm getting the error "'states' does not name a type".

WORKS

```
enum states
{
    DEMO, STATE1, STATE2
};
states currentState;
```

DOESNT WORK

```
states currentState;
enum states
{
    DEMO, STATE1, STATE2
};
```

Error

```
 error: 'states' does not name a type :states currentState
```

I'm only just recently getting into coding Arduino, and I never had this problem in C# or Java.

Comment: why can't you do it the way it works ?

Comment: Can use forward declaration `enum states;` for the part that doesn't work.

Comment: Because I like having my declaration above my functions and/or enums. If this is a thing in C++ it's a little disappointing

Comment: This has nothing to do with enums. You simply cannot use any name in C++ that has not previously been declared.

Comment: Okay, interesting... I didn't know that thanks. Why is my post being downvoted? Are simple questions not allowed on here?

Comment: Technically: yes. But you see, you have to draw the line somewhere ....

Comment: If a question like mine gets downvoted because it's too simple, I'm severely disappointed in the community of this site. Everyone is so damn grumpy, if you don't like the question move on, some people don't know everything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You must use forward declarations before using an identifier. If the size or functionality (e.g. class functions) must be known, then a full definition is required.

```
enum states; //forward declaration.
states currentState; // OK

//some other code
void foo(states currentState); //OK

enum states
{
    DEMO, STATE1, STATE2
};
```

Comment: why it doesn't work, can you show us the code with which you used `forward declaration`?

Comment: @vishal simply did it like this, it doesn't work. "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Comment: It works in VS2012 (C++ or C code), what did you try?

Comment: `enum` cannot be forward declared, `enum class` can.

Comment: This code compiles with VS2012 with default flags. This may be a VS specific extension. I didn't dig too deep into this.

Answer (score 1):

As state in comment, you can't use name without previous declaration in c++.

`enum` cannot be forward declared, but `enum class` can (introduced in C++11).

So you may do:

```
enum class states /* : int */ ; // forward declaration

states currentState;

enum class states /* : int */
{
    DEMO, STATE1, STATE2
};
```

Care though as `enum class` is different than simple `enum` with no explicit convertion to `int`.